# C++: no matching constructor for initialization / candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument, but no arguments were provided

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, initialization, nodes

I am trying to implement a linked list in C++ and don't know how to fix the error given below. I would greatly appreciate any help with debugging and, more importantly, an explanation of any underlying concepts that I don't understood regarding this error. Thanks.

Here is my error:

```
linkedList.cpp:19:23: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'NodeType'
        newnode = new NodeType;
                      ^
./linkedList.h:10:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'str', but no arguments
      were provided
        NodeType(const std::string str);
        ^
./linkedList.h:4:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1
      argument, but 0 were provided
class NodeType
      ^
linkedList.cpp:54:29: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'NodeType'
    NodeType* newnode = new NodeType;
                            ^
./linkedList.h:10:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'str', but no arguments
      were provided
        NodeType(const std::string str);
        ^
./linkedList.h:4:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1
      argument, but 0 were provided
class NodeType
      ^
```

Here is my NodeType class in my linkedList.h file:

```
  3 // define the node class
  4 class NodeType
  5 {
  6     private:
  7         std::string value;
  8         NodeType* next;
  9     public:
 10         NodeType(std::string str);
 11     friend class LinkedList;
 12 };
```

Here is the method in the linkedList.cpp file for the first error:

```
 10 LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& src)
 11 {
 12     head = NULL;
 13     NodeType* srccur; //node that is currently in src
 14     srccur = src.head;
 15 
 16     NodeType* pre = NULL; //predecessor of the new node
 17     while (srccur != NULL) // have not finished yet
 18     {   NodeType* newnode;
 19         newnode = new NodeType;
 20         if (newnode == NULL) //dynamic allocation failed
 21             { cout << "Memory allocation error" << endl;
 22                 exit(1);
 23             }
 24 
 25     newnode->value = srccur->value;
 26 
 27     if (pre == NULL)    //the new node becomes the 1st node
 28         head = newnode;
 29     else    // the new node is attached to the end
 30         pre->next = newnode;
 31 
 32     newnode->next = NULL;
 33 
 34     pre = newnode;
 35     srccur = srccur->next;
 36     }
 37 };
```

Here is the method in the linkedList.cpp file for the second error:

```
 53 bool LinkedList::insertFirst(string v){
 54     NodeType* newnode = new NodeType;
 55 
 56     if (newnode == NULL) // dynamic allocation failed
 57     {
 58         return false;
 59     }
 60 
 61     newnode->value = v;
 62     newnode->next = head;
 63 
 64     head = newnode;
 65 
 66     return true;
 67 };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple. Look at your constructor for `NodeType` (linkedList.h, line 10). It requires a single string. Yet, when you create new instances of `NodeType` (linkedList.cpp, line 18, line 54), you are calling the constructor *without* any arguments.

The proper way to do this would be...

```
NodeType* newnode = new NodeType("Some string.");
```

If you want that string argument in the constructor to be *optional*, you can do so by changing the constructor's header prototype to be...

```
NodeType(std::string str="Some default value");
```

Also, you could *overload* your constructor, having one for no arguments, one accepting a string, and so on.

---

Just so you know, that was a very basic principle. If you are a student (officially or unofficially), you'll want to review C++ Object Oriented Programming, specifically "Constructors".

Comment: Yeah... I learned Python first and will be the first to admit that my understanding of C++ is very incomplete at this point. Thanks for the informative answer. I'll take your advice, as well.

Comment: @SergeiWallace, I made that transition as well, and picked up on OOP in C++. This is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list